# Pages - new paragraph in the same list item?

Tags: pages, iwork

I create a numbered list:

```
1. Point 1
2. Point 2
```

and so on. Now I realised that the content of 2 requires two paragraphs

```
1. Point 1
2. Point 2, paragraph 1
   Point 2, paragraph 2
```

but pressing enter in a list just creates a new list entry.

Shift-Enter gives a new line but not the extra space you want to separate the paragraphs (c.f., this paragraph and the previous paragraph):

```
1. Point 1
2. Point 2, paragraph 1

   Point 2, paragraph 2
```

(There is too much space in this example but you hopefully get the point.)

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Is there some reason you can not press shift-enter twice?

Comment: Have you tried making it 2a. and 2b.?  or do you not want that?

Comment: @user3439894 Wrong line spacing.

Comment: @jmh Don't want that. It just that some points in this list are too long for a single paragraph if they are to be comfortable to read.

Comment: @hensti, RE: "Wrong line spacing" ... Is there some reason you cannot change the font size for the line separating the paragraphs to decrease the amount of space between the two paragraphs?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. Just duplicate the current list style and make the new style without a bullet in the appropriate section of the *Format* sidebar. Pages is smart enough to continue the numbering on the next paragraph where it left of in the previous paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

You could use <kbd>Ctrl-Return</kbd> if you would like to use a **line break** (to write in a new line without starting a new paragraph). For example, if you want to start a new line within the same number in a numbered list, you can use this.

The introduction to the **line break** function can be found on [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/pages-icloud/gil2bc7f5230/icloud).

And the keyboard shortcut for inserting a line break [according to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/pages/tanc0ffef022/mac) is still <kbd>Shift-Return</kbd> which does not work for me. It seems that Apple made this change some time ago but I cannot find any guide from Apple saying that <kbd>Ctrl-Return</kbd> is now used for inserting line break.

Comment: Is this an actual answer or is this a question/comment in an attempt to gain more clarity?

Comment: This works for me when I want to write something in a new line but still under the same number in a numbered list. @Allan

Comment: Would you consider expanding your answers further by explaining how it works for you?  As it reads now, it sounds like you’re not exactly sure

Comment: The answer is correct, but is short enough to give people (or the Community Bot) concern that it's low quality. You could perhaps quote the relevant passage from the Pages help to give it a bit more weight, as Allan suggests.

Comment: Thank you Allan and Andy for your advice, I have changed it and added some links.

Answer (score 0):

You can press **space-enter** twice to create the visual *line* break between *paragraphs*, and then change the **font size**, **⌘-** for the *line* separating the *paragraphs* to decrease the amount of space between the two *paragraphs*.

You can also press **⇧⌘I** to **Show Invisibles**, or click **Pages** > **View** > **Show Invisibles**, which may makes it easier to select the *line* to decrease its *font size*